# weights inside a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

In my App i am trying to create a scroll view that has 3 big buttons that fills the entire screen. so every button's size is 1/3 of the screen.  How can I do that?
When I am using weights its not working .

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/main_btn_call" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/main_btn_unlock" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/main_btn_push" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What are the exact size of the images which you are using as Buttons?

Comment: Why is the size metter? they are about 150dp.

Comment: Please define "they don't work". Don't forget that you need to provide a [mre] for your question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

The only change is  add the following property in your XML:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and your scroll view width and height should be `match_parent`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `TableLayout` which is a `LinearLayout` with orientation set to `vertical` - This is all fine so far, you using weights on the `layout_height` attribute.

The problem as I see it is that you're using `wrap_content` in both your `ScrollView` and in your `TableLayout`. Weight values allow your views to expand to fill space available to it but your parent is wrapping the content to 0 + 0 + 0. If you change the hight to `match_parent` for both parent  elements your weight values will have space to expand

Comment: this is not working for me..

Comment: in what way isn't it working?

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: You haven't described in your question what the original problem was (what is displaying and what way is this "not working").

Comment: the problem is that the images are not sizing them self by the weights, they act like there are no weights in there.  the just stack one on the other and not to fill the screen.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I meneged to do this with code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView incallImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.incall_image);
    final ImageView unlockImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.unlock_image);
    final ImageView pushImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.push_image);
    final ScrollView scrollViewMain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_main);
    scrollViewMain.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollMainHeight = scrollViewMain.getHeight();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new    
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, scrollMainHeight / 3);
            incallImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            unlockImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            pushImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone finds a way to do this in the xml it will be great!,
Thanks!